# Symfony login application - sample data doesn't add to the Database

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony. I am working on a sample login,signup application using a video tutorial in the link https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsvlmJMhAkNcbN9FU-5n8Pw

I have followed the same code structure.here is my controller code

```
public function signupAction(Request $request) {
        if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") {
            $userName = $request->get('username');
            $firstName = $request->get('firstname');
            $password = $request->get('password');

            $user = new Users(); 
            $user = setUserName($userName);
            $user = setFirstName($firstName);            
            $user = setPassword($password);            

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

        }
        return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:signup.html.twig');
    }
```

I have created a database named users and a table named users. have inserted one data with user_name,first_name,password.
With the above could it works fine in the video tutorial. but in my application when i click create account button it shows a blank page.Could someone help me out

Comment: Blank page means (often) that there's a 500 error. Turn on showing errors and see what you've got.

Comment: You'll burn in hell for storing plaintext passwords :/

Comment: Hi matiit... thanks for the reply.. i found in the error log. it shows the following error.....emergency.EMERGENCY: Call to undefined function Login\LoginBundle\Controller\setUserName() {"type":1,"file":"D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\LoginProject\\src\\Login\\LoginBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController.php","line":34} []

Comment: @nishanth so maybe try with `setUsername`?

Comment: You need to invoke `setUserName` of `$user` and not controller's one ;) See the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :)

```
$user = new Users(); 
$user->setUserName($userName);
$user->setFirstName($firstName);            
$user->setPassword($password);
```

So, the syntax is not `OBJECT = METHOD` but rather `OBJECT->METHOD` ;)

Comment: This works fine.. A row of data is added to my database but user_name data is empty... When i created my entity file i.e the Users.php it has the getfirstname , setFirstName , getPassword, setPassword, getUserName.But setUserName alone not created .. so added it my own ... but theuser_name in database is empty when i signup a user... could u help me out..... thanks in advance...

Comment: Hm, that is weird. Be as it may all IDEs (e.g. Eclipse, NetBeans, PhpStorm) support auto generation of get* and set* methods.